# Running NSURLConnection after while loop

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to call a method from a custom class i created that calls `NSURLConnection` in it, But my `NSURLConnection` seems to be unexecuted.

Here's my code :

```
int a = 0;

while(a < 10)
{
   a++;
}

if (a == 10)
{
    NSString *q = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/myURL.txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURLRequest *url = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:q]];
    NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:url delegate:self];
}
```

The code above should get a url from a txt file and call it, When it's called it must create a new directory but it's not.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Does `q` have the expected value? Is `url` as expected? Do you process the connection?

Comment: Yes, it gets the expected value but for some reason 'NSURLConnection' not executing.

Comment: Did you implement the needed protocol methods to handle the connection's data?

Comment: No, what do you mean by that ?

Comment: ...read my answer below..you need that

Comment: @user3638590 I think you should take some time to read the docs for `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch the connection:

```
NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                             startImmediately:YES];
```

or:

```
NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL 
                                                     delegate:self];
```

Then, if you want receive the event of this object, be sure to make your close conforms to protocol `NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`. So in your file header (`.h`):

```
@interface YourClass <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

and in your file implementation (`.m`) for example you can write the method called when the connection finish to load:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //your code
}
```

You will see the other delegate methods in the apple documentation.

If you want run this in another thread, you should run the method in the main thread and then pass a queue to the URLConnection:

```
NSOperationQueue *networkOperationsQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestURL 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                             startImmediately:NO];
[c setDelegateQueue:networkOperationsQueue];
[c start];
```

In any case your code above is redundant:

```
while(a < 10)
{
   a++;
}

if (a == 10)
```

If you are in a `while cycle` and wait the that `a == 10` to go **out for the while**, you **don't need to check if a is equal 10**..because is so.

Comment: Still not working, i've tried also running the url using '[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:q]];' but it doesn't open the link. Please note that this method is running on background.

Comment: You haven't to run it in background..if you want run this in another thread you can use the queue (you can set a queue with setDelegateQueue. See my update.

Comment: Well, i tell you all..so is evident that you have other problems in your code..can you log the URL that you read from the file? What behaviour do you waiting for after the NSURLConnection?

Comment: Yes i logged the url and it's correct. After NSURLConnection a file should be created on my server.

Comment: are you launching the NSURLConnection on the main thread? are you sure??

Comment: Yes,"[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];"

Comment: The method, initWithRequest:delegate: starts the request without having to call start, and is equivalent to passing YES to the initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method.

Comment: ok edited. Anyway, i would need to debug your code...are you sure that your backend file work properly (e.g. create the file if called from the browser)? Are you sure that your backend file doesn't want some header in the request to make able to create the file? there a lot of variable..